# parse database - set download timeout (objective c)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, download, timeout

I am downloading the data for my app from parse.com, but I need to know how to set a timeout if it takes too long for the data to download. I already have an internet connection check, and if there is a connection it will download the data, but if the internet is very slow I need the download to timeout so the user isn't waiting a long time and therefore unable to use the app. Please help me how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

use timer. after sometime just call the method.inside the method cancel the downloading

```
NSTimer *timerTimeOut = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(timeOutTriggered) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

method definition

```
 - (void)timeOutTriggered{
if( isDownloading )
{
    isDownloading = NO;
    [urlConnection cancel];
    [urlConnection release];          
}

isDownloading = NO;

 if( webData != nil ){
    [webData release];
    webData = nil;
 }
}
```